# Stackable DIV based grid

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, responsive, footable

I am looking for a way to implement grid like [FooTable](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/). which is responsive and stacks columns based on screen size as demonstrated in site page. But problem is that `Footable` works on `HTML Table` only. And my grid renders `DIV`s instead of table.

So I would like to know that whether such library is available which can stack columns with expand collapse view based on screen size.

Comment: Questions asking for external tools, libraries, or resources are [off topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what you have done so far to solve it.

Comment: I would have described the problem. But I don't know how to achieve such feature. That's why I am posting query here expecting someone might have an idea.

Comment: You have a couple options - change your grid to a table so you can use FooTable (if it's tabular data it would be semantically correct to put into a table anyway), or do some research online. SO isn't the place to ask questions about how to find libraries or get information about 3rd party stuff - that information will grow stale and is opinionated. Those may be good questions for other forums, but are off topic here.